# Ascii not converted in commons lang3

Tags: java

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("Cortés")` is working in commons-lang2.3 but not working in 3.2.1. Expected output is `"Cort&#233;s"` but actual output is `"Cortes"`.

Comment: Well aside from anything else, é isn't an ASCII character...

Answer (score 0):

`escapeXml()` is deprecated in 3.2.1. Use `escapeXml10()` or `escapeXml11()` instead.

Alternatively, from the documentation:

> Note that Unicode characters greater than 0x7f are as of 3.0, no longer escaped. If you still wish this functionality, you can achieve it via the following: `StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_XML.with( NumericEntityEscaper.between(0x7f, Integer.MAX_VALUE) );`